# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

This [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155730/5656) on the question [What rate do non-competitive bids get at Treasury bond auctions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155728/5656) was deleted. Why?

The only comment left by one of the delete voters is:

> You're seriously quoting random comments as an authoritative answer.

which is incorrect, as the answer quotes a published article (*Garbade, Kenneth, and Jeffrey Ingber. "[The treasury auction process: Objectives, structure, and recent adaptations.](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/current_issues/ci11-2.pdf)" Structure, and Recent Adaptations (2005). ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/us-treasury-auction-process))*).

---

Here's the answer:

> > does that mean that all non-competitive bids got the low rate (3.100%)?
>
> No. All competitive and noncompetitive bids that are filled receive the same rate, which is highest filled bid rate (= the rate of the lowest filled bid, since the lower the bid, the higher the bid rate).
>
> [Source 1](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/current_issues/ci11-2.pdf) {1} (thanks [0xFEE1DEAD](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/50601/0xfee1dead) for [pointing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155723/is-it-financially-preferable-to-purchase-treasury-bonds-on-the-primary-market-or#comment319815_155726) me to it):
>
> > All auction awards are made at a single price, computed from the yield at which the auction stopped.
>
> [Source 2](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/2907/5656) (thanks [0xFEE1DEAD](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/50601/0xfee1dead) for [pointing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155728/what-rate-do-non-competitive-bids-get-at-treasury-bond-auctions?noredirect=1#comment319822_155728) me to it):
>
> > Bid 4 was the last accepted competitive bid, its max price will be the price that all (both competitive and noncompetitive) bidders will receive.
>
> ---
>
> References:
>
> - {1} Garbade, Kenneth, and Jeffrey Ingber. "[The treasury auction process: Objectives, structure, and recent adaptations.](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/current_issues/ci11-2.pdf)" Structure, and Recent Adaptations (2005). ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/us-treasury-auction-process))

Answer (score 5):

IIRC it was downvoted into oblivion as it was low-quality and inaccurate.

> Answers can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any answer, and trusted community members can vote to delete answers that have a score of -1 or lower (3 votes will result in deletion).

https://money.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: I had fixed the inaccuracy.  Why low-quality?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you're entitled to your opinion but the downvoters don't owe you anything, as frustrating as that may be for you.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you think the answer is low-quality?

Comment: Neither your question nor answer add anything to the question this was duped to.

Comment: @littleadv This answer is buried in the question this was duped to. [How do I participate in Treasury auctions with my millions of dollars?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/2886/5656) is very far away from [What rate do non-competitive bids get at Treasury bond auctions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155728/5656)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The great thing about a score-based system is that the community gets to vote which questions/answers are the most useful, eliminating the need to debate them ad nauseum...